# How to Embedd semicolons in asp.net MVC4 razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a URL I want to build that looks like this:

```
   http://cache.mysite.com/sponsorimage/718.jpg;format=gif;w=50;h=50;scale=both;mode=pad;bgcolor=white
```

The razor to create it is this:

```
   @(sponsor.ImageURL)
   <img src="@(sponsor.ImageURL)&#59;format=gif&#59;w=50&#59;h=50&#59;scale=both&#59;mode=pad&#59;bgcolor=white" alt="@sponsor.SponsorName"  />
```

This just feels ugly. I'm new to razor.  what's a better way to do this.  That is, embedding semicolons in the string (I'm not using ? and & on purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I would use string.Format:

```
src="@(string.Format("{0};format=gif;w=50;h=50;scale=both;mode=pad;bgcolor=white", sponsor.ImageURL))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very verbose, but more generic.

```
@{
    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder();
    NameValueCollection queries = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(ub.Query)
    queries.Add("format", "gif")
    queries.Add("w", "59")
    queries.Add("h", "50")
    queries.Add("scale", "both")
    queries.Add("mode", "pad")
    queries.Add("bgcolor", "white")
    ub.Query = queries.ToString()
}

<img src="@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sponsor.ImageURL & ub.Query.Replace("?", ";").Replace("&", ";"))" />
```